# Modal not displaying in center of page with flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

```
 <div className="modals">
   <div className="channelModal" >
       <Modal className="modal" isOpen={this.state.isChannelModalOpen} onClose={() => this.closeChannelModal()}>
         <h1>Create a Channel</h1>
         <p><button onClick={() => this.createChannel()}>Create Channel</button></p>
       </Modal>
     </div>
   </div>
```

css

```
.modals {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I'm not sure why this wont position it in the centre. it is just hugging the left handside. any ideas how to make this display in the centre of the page using flexbox?

Comment: is that the only styles? if so, that only aligns the content inside the modals to the center of the modals div

Comment: When did the `modal` tag become a thing?

Comment: @Mooseman https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

Comment: @Theworm That's just sad.

Comment: @Mooseman whys it sad?

Comment: @Theworm Semantics and spec.